# Open Chrome popup from command line

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I want to open a Chrome popup from a known URL from windows command line. I know `start` can be used to open webpages, but not popups.

Comment: "start can be used to open webpages, but not popups" - So the popup isn't a webpage too?

Comment: http://www.twitch.tv/DreamhackSpeedRun/chat?popout=

It doesn't open as a popup, same as it would if you went to http://www.twitch.tv/DreamhackSpeedRun/chat clicked on the gear -> popup

Comment: What you call a popup is just a new browser window with a specific size.

Comment: Without bars, header, options...what's been a popup since 1996!